# SQL sample app stop running on execution in Android Studio

Tags: android, sql

I am new to Android Studio.

I am trying to run a simple SQL bases app for storing and deleting data. But the app keep on crashing when running in the emulator. I have tried several suggestions available here but nothing worked.

Here's the code.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.barhigmail.lucky.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ADD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addbuttonclicked"
        android:text="ADD"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="152dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.73" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/INPUT_NAME"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/INPUT_QUANTITY"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="156dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/INPUT_PRICE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="86dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ITEMNAME"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:text="  ITEMNAME"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ITEMPRICE"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:text="   ITEMPRICE"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="86dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ITEMQUANTITY"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:text="   QUANTITY"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="165dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PRINT"
        android:layout_width="358dp"
        android:layout_height="206dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="591dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


main.java

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText INPUT_NAME,INPUT_PRICE,INPUT_QUANTITY;
    TextView PRINT;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        INPUT_NAME=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.INPUT_NAME);
        INPUT_PRICE=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.INPUT_PRICE);
        INPUT_QUANTITY=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.INPUT_QUANTITY);
        dbHandler=new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);

        printdatabase();
    }


    public void addbuttonclicked() {

        Products product= new Products(INPUT_NAME.getText().toString(),INPUT_PRICE.getText().toString(),INPUT_QUANTITY.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addproduct(product);
        printdatabase();

    }


    public  void printdatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databasetostring();
        PRINT.setText(dbString);
        INPUT_NAME.setText("");
        INPUT_PRICE.setText("");
        INPUT_QUANTITY.setText("");


    }
}


Products.java

public class Products {

    private int _id;
    private String _productname;
    private String _productprice;
    private String _productquantity;

    public Products(){

    }

    public Products(String _productname, String _productprice, String _productquantity) {
        this._productname = _productname;
        this._productprice = _productprice;
        this._productquantity = _productquantity;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void set_productname(String _productname) {
        this._productname = _productname;
    }

    public void set_productprice(String _productprice) {
        this._productprice = _productprice;
    }

    public void set_productquantity(String _productquantity) {
        this._productquantity = _productquantity;
    }




    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_productname() {
        return _productname;
    }

    public String get_productprice() {
        return _productprice;
    }

    public String get_productquantity() {
        return _productquantity;
    }
}


MyDBHandler.java

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="products.db";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME="productname";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTPRICE="productprice";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTQUANTITY="productquantity";

    private static final String query = " create table " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,  " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " text not null, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTPRICE + " integer not null, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTQUANTITY + " integer not null);" ;


    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {



        db.execSQL(query);
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w(MyDBHandler.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    //adding new rows

    public void addproduct(Products product){

        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        SQLiteDatabase db= getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }


    //converting database to string

    public String databasetostring() {

        String dbString = " ";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "WHERE 1";

        //cursur positioning

        Cursor c= db.rawQuery(query,null);
        c.moveToFirst();


        while (!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"))!=null){

                dbString +=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productprice")) +
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productquantity"));
                dbString +="\n";

            }

        }

        db.close();
        return dbString;



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post crash logs(logcat)

Comment: You are question is so broad, No one can give the solution without knowing the actual problem. When your app crashes go to the bottom of Android Studio, there will be a tab named "Android Monitor" click on that, it will show the logs of issues/cause of crash. Post those logs along with your code. So someone can understand the problem.